# Gerund + Noun vs. Noun + Noun vs. Adjective + Noun

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, word-usage, gerunds

What's the difference between these three? Are they all grammatically correct?

> 1. "Migrating behavior"

or

> 2. "Migration behavior"

or

> 3. "Migratory behavior"

Which one should I say?

I have searched google scholar and found out that there are some papers using "Migration behavior" and some other papers using "Migratory behavior", so I am a little bit confused.

Thanks.

Comment: It would depend on what you are trying to convey and what context you are using the phrase in. Could you contextualise the phrases please?

Comment: *For example,* is wrong. It is **not** an example, it is *the actual* set of words. ++ It will depend on the context. **You must give a sentence that provides context and includes the words you are asking about.** ++ Without context, “Migrating” in “migrating behaviour” cannot be explained. In that phrase, “*migrating*” can be a participle, a verbal noun, or a gerund and it could be acting as a verb or a noun or an adjective. -- *Are they all Grammarly correct?* I have no idea, I don’t have the app. In any case, “Grammarly” is merely a reasonable starting point – it is not 100% reliable.

Comment: 'Migrating behaviour' is the least used in the context in which the others apply because it is ambiguous. It could be used to imply that it was the _behaviour_ which was migrating, not the population. An example would be 'We are migrating the behaviour of computer application A to application B".

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with any one of these, there's simply a different form of the word acting as modifier to the noun.

Searching on the iWeb corpus gets:

migrating behavior - 7 hits

migratory behavior - 133 hits

migration behavior - 29 hits

So it would seem the safe bet is *migratory behavior*.

Comment: However, without context, and simply as they are, surely the modifiers change the meaning. 1. Migrating behaviour would imply a behaviour that moves from one place to another. 2. Migratory behaviour would imply a specific behaviour in connection with the act of moving from one place to another and 3. Migration behaviour would imply the overall behaviours of migration.

Comment: They're used pretty much interchangeably in the examples I reviewed with _migrat**ing**_ popping up when a few -ing words had come immediately before.

Comment: @DW256 The number of times a word is used is not indicative of its accurate use in a given context.

Comment: @Greybeard, when they're used pretty much interchageably, as in this case, it's a pretty good indicator of which is more likely to be most acceptable to most people

Comment: @DW256 The OP is asking for the differences, **not** the similarities or whether they are interchangeable, or whether people use the words loosely. We really do need context. :)

Comment: @Greybeard, OP asked which one to use, and in the context of papers using either Migratory Behavior or Migration Behavior, the choice is faily clear. Also, interchangeability and smiliarity does tell us about the lack of difference between them, thus answering his question. Anything but use statistics is likely to be opinion based in this case. ;)

Comment: @DW256 I read "*What's the difference between these three?*" - I do not read *which one to use*. There are differences in use and meaning.

Comment: Well, look again. The OP asked at the end "Which one should I say?", which is the equivalent to "which one to use" How much clearer can it be?

Comment: @DW Ignore the negative comments.This is a reasonable answer. It seems clear that we are looking for the most likely modifier of the noun "behaviour" to describe the behaviour of animals (typically birds) during their migration. Personally, I'd go for "migratory", since it is an adjective, while "migrating" is a verb, and "migration" is a noun, but I wouldn't rule them out.